# How to substitute value in numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very easy question but somehow I'm having trouble with it...

I'm creating an 81x41 string 2d-array with numpy. I then iterate through all positions of this array and want to put a certain string inside each position.

For some reason, it doesn't assign the variable to the position. It remains empty.

How can I do this simple value assignment? What am I missing?

My code:

```py
def create_discrete_values(self, threshold: list[int]):
        self.map_index_discreet = np.ndarray(shape=(81, 41), dtype=str)

        for i in range(81):
            for j in range(41):
                val = self.map_index[i][j]
                discreet_value = None
                if val <= threshold[0]:
                    discreet_value = "Very Low"
                elif val <= threshold[1]:
                    discreet_value = "Low"
                elif val <= threshold[2]:
                    discreet_value = "Moderate"
                elif val <= threshold[3]:
                    discreet_value = "High"
                elif val <= threshold[4]:
                    discreet_value = "Very High"
                elif val <= threshold[5]:
                    discreet_value = "Extreme"
                else:
                    discreet_value = "Very Extreme"

                self.map_index_discreet[i][j] = discreet_value
```

Comment: did you examine `self.map_index_discreet`?

Comment: @hjpaulj just updated the question. Noticed a major error. But still not working. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: `ndarray` suggests we use `Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty`.  But in any case, look at the `dtype` of that array.  With numpy arrays, strings have a fixed maximum length.  They aren't like python base strings which can be any length.

Comment: Did you first write this for python strings and lists, and are now trying to port it to arrays?  If so, why?  It's not going to improve speed.

Comment: When you make a `string` dtype array you should specify a string size, for example `U10`, that can hold any of the desired strings.  Plain `str` produces some thing like `U0`, which can't hold any characters.  Numpy strings are not a dropin replacement for python lists and strings.

Comment: If you want any help with comparing alternatives - lists versus arrays, different dtypes etc, you'll have to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dtype='object'` which will assign a pointer and will allow you to put whatever in the cell. If you are concerned about performance, then you might want to use `dtype='U<length>'` which will assign memory for a Unicode string of size `<length>`. If you assign a longer string, it will simply be cut off (which might not be what you want...).

```py
import numpy as np
map_index_discreet = np.ndarray(shape=(81, 41), dtype='U10')

for i in range(81):
    for j in range(41):
        map_index_discreet[i][j] = str(i) + '_' + str(j)
print(map_index_discreet[3][4])
#>>> '3_4'
map_index_discreet[3][4] = 'longer than 10'
print(map_index_discreet[3][4])
#>>> 'longer tha'
```

`dtype='str'` without initializing the array with some data is like defining a `dtype='U0'`, which is quite useless as you found out. It makes, however sense if you wanted to initialize a mixed-type array and force it into a string array like so:

```py
# forcing the array to dtype='str'
np.array(['abc', None, False, 'abdedf'], dtype='str')
#>>> array(['abc', 'None', 'False', 'abdedf'], dtype='<U6')
```

As you can see, Numpy looks for the longest string in the data to determine the dtype of the string array.

The performance implications of `'str'/'U<length>` vs. `'object'` depend very much on your use case. If you are not dealing with large amounts of data, then you should probably just stick to `dtype='object'`.

See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.interface.html#arrays-interface) for the relevant Numpy documenation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dtype=object. When creating an array with dtype=str the array can only contain strings with equal or lower length than the maximum element. Since your array is empty, that length is 0.